# Transaction from non-miner node is not getting mined sometimes

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, private-blockchain, mining, json-rpc

I have a private Ethereum network containing 2 nodes,NodeA and NodeB.
When I initiate a sendTransaction from NodeA(non-mining node) to deploy Ethereum contract using JSON-RPC, the transaction hash is returned.

Then I initiate NodeB(mining node) to start mining.
But sometimes, the transaction receipt is not obtained. And the transaction remains in pending Transactions.

Then if I start mining on NodeA, then the transaction Receipt is obtained.
And the transaction is success.

Why is it happening like this?? Any help would be appreciated